# Swift : How to recover data from a Sensortag 2.0 device

Tags: swift

I need your help to understand how to recover the data from a Sensortag 2.0 device.

**I have the following information:**

- Transfert: BLE
- Service: f000fff0-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
- Characteristics: f000fff1-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
- Notification with the following characteristic:
  f000fff2-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
- start command: 0x73 or 0x53
- end command: 0x65 or 0x45
- 1 packets 20Byte
- The second Byte is used as the discrimination code.

**My test:**

To help me to understand, I use this source code:
https://github.com/degtiarev/DataCollector

**1) On the Device.swift file, I added the UUID like this:**

```
static let TestServiceUUID = "f000fff0-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"
static let TestCharacteristicsUUID = "f000fff1-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"
static let TestNotificationUUID = "f000fff1-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"
```

**2) On the CollectingDataVC.swift, I changed the sensorTagName like that:**

```
let sensorTagName = "my-device"
```

**3) I added my service:**

```
if let services = peripheral.services {
    for service in services {
        print("Discovered service \(service)")
        // If we found movement service, discover the characteristics for those services.
        if (service.uuid == CBUUID(string: Device.MovementServiceUUID)) ||
            (service.uuid == CBUUID(string: Device.TestServiceUUID)) ||
            (service.uuid == CBUUID(string: Device.IOServiceUUID)) || (service.uuid == CBUUID(string: Device.SimpleKeyUUID)) {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }
}
```

**4) I added the characteristics**:

```
for characteristic in characteristics {

    // Test
    if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: Device.TestCharacteristicsUUID) {
        movementCharacteristics[peripheral.identifier.uuidString] = characteristic
        sensorTags[peripheral.identifier.uuidString]?.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
    }

    if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: Device.TestNotificationUUID) {
        movementCharacteristics[peripheral.identifier.uuidString] = characteristic
        sensorTags[peripheral.identifier.uuidString]?.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
    }

}
```

The program works because my devise is connected, and I have this informations on my console:

```
SENSOR TAG FOUND! ADDING NOW!!!
**** SUCCESSFULLY CONNECTED TO SENSOR TAG!!!


======= SERVICES ========
▿ Optional([<CBService: 0x1c0677a40, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>, <CBService: 0x1c0678180, isPrimary = YES, UUID = F000FFF0-0451-4000-B000-000000000000>])
  ▿ some: 2 elements
    - <CBService: 0x1c0677a40, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information> #0
      - super: CBAttribute
        - super: NSObject
    - <CBService: 0x1c0678180, isPrimary = YES, UUID = F000FFF0-0451-4000-B000-000000000000> #1
      - super: CBAttribute
        - super: NSObject
==========


Discovered service <CBService: 0x1c0677a40, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>
Discovered service <CBService: 0x1c0678180, isPrimary = YES, UUID = F000FFF0-0451-4000-B000-000000000000>


======= CHARACTERISTICS ========
▿ 2 elements
  - <CBCharacteristic: 0x1c42a3c60, UUID = F000FFF1-0451-4000-B000-000000000000, properties = 0xA, value = (null), notifying = NO> #0
    - super: CBAttribute
      - super: NSObject
  - <CBCharacteristic: 0x1c42a4320, UUID = F000FFF2-0451-4000-B000-000000000000, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO> #1
    - super: CBAttribute
      - super: NSObject
==========
```

**4) From here, I do not know what to do.**

I created a "Hello World" :

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

  print("Hello World!")

}
```

But this code is never executed.
It's my first program on swift, so I need some help to understand and to know what I must to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the project you are using and they have already given a description about method use and when it will call which is:

```
 Invoked when you retrieve a specified characteristic’s value,
 or when the peripheral device notifies your app that the characteristic’s value has changed.

 This method is invoked when your app calls the readValueForCharacteristic: method,
 or when the peripheral notifies your app that the value of the characteristic for
 which notifications and indications are enabled has changed.

 If successful, the error parameter is nil.
 If unsuccessful, the error parameter returns the cause of the failure.
```

And

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
```

above method is a delegate method of `CBPeripheralDelegate` which is

```
optional public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.
precisely, this method is never called

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

  print("Hello World!")

}

Comment: have you set the delegate for `CBPeripheralDelegate`?